# onchange event not working in dropdown menu added from another php page using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

i want to display all table list from a database in drop down menu and allow user to select table name. when user selects table name i want to show all the data. html file is like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $.ajax({url:"home.php?id=1",
                success:function(result){
                    $("#div1").html(result);                 
                }}); 

            $("#dropdown").change(function(){
                alert("list item selected");
                $.ajax({url:"home.php?id=2&tablename="+tableForm.tableLists.value,
                    success:function(result){
                        $("#div2").html(result);
                    }}); 
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button value="add" >
        <form name="tableForm"> 
            <div id="div1"></div>
        </form>
    </button>
    <br><hr>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</body>
```

this page runs okay and displays a list of alltable name  belonging to database. but when i select a value from the dropdown list it doesnt even alert **"list item selected"** messsage. what to do to make it work ??

here is the an image of dropdown list
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the dropdown box is dynamically loaded into the page, so you must bind the function to the dynamically added element using `.on()`:

```
$(document).on('change', '#dropdown', function(){
    console.log("list item selected");
    // do whatever here
});
```

- [jQuery API: .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: ya it worked. i just updated the jquery.js file with jquery-1.8.2.min.js file thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think dropdown box is loaded dynamically into the page. You can use like that

```
$("#dropdown").on('change',function(){
                alert("hoi");
                $.ajax({url:"home.php?id=2&tablename="+tableForm.tableLists.value,
                    success:function(result){
                        $("#div2").html(result);
                    }}); 
            });
```

Comment: For `.on()` to function like the `.live()` function, it needs to be bound to the `document` event instead of the actual element itself (which would act more like the `.bind()` function).

Answer (score 0):

As your code suggests that you are populating your dropdown dynamically and in your code you are giving a local event which will not work there are several other event handlers like `.on` `.bind` `.live` etc, if i have to work in this kind of situation i would definetly prefer to use `.on` or `.live` so your code has to be like these:

```
$("#dropdown").live('change',function(){
    alert("list item selected");
    $.ajax({
       url:"home.php?id=2&tablename="+tableForm.tableLists.value,
       success:function(result){
            $("#div2").html(result);
          }
    }); 
});
```

or this:

```
 $("#dropdown").on('change',function(){
    alert("list item selected");
    $.ajax({
       url:"home.php?id=2&tablename="+tableForm.tableLists.value,
       success:function(result){
            $("#div2").html(result);
          }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: there is no error , no warnings no exceptions and still its not alerting even the first message. if i use .on() does it shows the source code of the dynamically loaded part of code ??